# Good practice to deal with POST api and loss of internet connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, rest, http

I own an hybrid application, whose main language is Javascript (AngularJs) so.
Basically, I have a form aiming to create an object through my REST api (on a distinct server).

My `save` function is conceptually like this:

```
$scope.save = function () {
  var promise = CRUDService.post($scope.myElementToPost);
  promise.then(function (response) {
      //when 20X status
  }, function () {
      //when 40X - 50X status
  });            
};
```

Let's suppose the triggering of the `save` function, and really immediately after the `POST` request, the mobile loses internet connection, leading to an error **at client side**, therefore involving the **error callback**.

In this "exceptional" case, the element would be well created on server's database, but the javascript success callback would not be triggered, since a loss of internet connection leads to an "error".

How to deal with this case?
How to avoid user to re-submit the form (he would be ignorant of the first creation of the element on the server side)?

Comment: Seems like this should be a two part solution. Part 1: post sent to server; no result yet. Part 2: what was the result of that action? Don't tie the creation directly to the initial post, tie it to the result you query for when you have connectivity.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker May you rephrase ? I don't figure out your point.

Comment: What bad things would happen in this scenario?  Why are you trying to deal with it?

Comment: Two elements are created => duplicate.  Indeed, first the user gets a kind of message "Sorry, there was a technical error, check your connection", ( ignoring that the post call already succeeded), then he clicks again on "Create" leading to a " great , you've just created your element !" , ignoring that this later is a duplicate. It sounds very tricky when server processes while client connection is lost triggering an error at client side, as if the api call failed completely (but didn't)

Comment: use an unique id for the element you send to the server, you if you receive it again don't create a new one, just update the existing.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Your solution would work as long as the server process succeeds. If it fails, user couldn't end up with a created element.

Answer (score 3):

You may create a transaction model:

1. Client creates a unique transaction ID for this request and attach to the Rest call
2. Server receives the request, check the transaction log for previous calls with the same id.
3. if it is a new transaction, server stores this transaction ID in a log with a status 'pending'. Server then processes the request. Server updates the transaction log status to 'processed'. Server then sends the response to the client
   and stores response in the transaction log
4. If it is an old transaction, server resend response to client
5. Client receives response, client sends transaction completed signal to the server.
6. Server removes/updates transaction log to 'finished'

Failure in the 5th step, the client can resend the request with the same transaction id, without the risk of duplicate records